# How to Maintain Foreign Key Constraint Across Different Databases?

Tags: mysql, database-design, symfony1

I know, *I know*, putting two related tables on different databases isn't exactly the best design practice. But for whatever's sake, suppose that I *have* to do it absolutely. And I have to break up two foreign-key-related tables that were previously located in a database into two databases, **that are located on two different servers**, but I still want to maintain the database(s) integrity. What is the best way to do this?

**Edit: I am using MySQL and Symfony**

Comment: I think you'll need to tell us what database you're using, the answer (other than JUST DON'T) will probably be very dependent on your stack.

Comment: Are these tables in two different mysql instances or in two different catalogs inside the same mysql instance?

Comment: Hmm, actually the tables are located at different databases, and these two databases are located at different servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do this with standard MySQL.

You could write a plugin for [MySQL Proxy](https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy), that manages referential integrity between the parent and child tables on different servers:

- Intercept `INSERT` and `UPDATE` against child table.  Query for matching row in parent table.  Fail `INSERT`/`UPDATE` if no match found in parent table.
- Intercept `DELETE` against parent table.  Query for dependent rows in child table.  Fail `DELETE` if any dependent rows found in child table.  If the constraint is intended to support cascading behavior, do that instead of failing.
- Intercept `UPDATE` against parent table.  If the primary key value is changing as part of the update, query for dependent rows found in child table.  Fail `UPDATE` if any dependent rows found in child table.  If the constraint is intended to support cascading behavior, do that instead of failing.

Note that you'd have to keep information about the referential integrity constraints in your MySQL Proxy plugin (or write a custom config file for your plugin that records the relationships).  You can't use conventional `FOREIGN KEY` syntax to declare such constraints across MySQL instances.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [Federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)? These are basically *links* to tables which are hosted on a different databases on a different/same host.

You can create a federated table locally and use that to enforce referential integrity. However, I cannot overemphasize the fact that this approach is fraught with future gotchas and not at all recommended.

Comment: Foreign keys are not supported at all for FEDERATED tables.  There's a talk at the MySQL Conference in April about the *possibility* of future support of FK in distributed tables in MySQL 6.1!