# mysql db with parent child relation

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

Can somebody help me with a archietecture design?

Problem statement is I have a many local db which gets populated with data. Now this data needs to be collected to a central db for further processing.

Its like there is one parent and multiple childs. Child do not need to sync with the parent but parent needs to take data from the child for further processing.

I am using mysql db. Is there any tool which can help me out with this?

Adding to this my childs db are on seperate server and my parent db is on seperate server

Answer (score 0):

There are few key points

- set Engine of all tables as 'INNODB'
- set foreign key(FK)reference between child and parent
- set ON UPDATE and ON DELETE constraints while creating FK

UPDATE:

if you have different table on different server then use Use [FEDERATED Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)

see [`Reference`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for more

Comment: Edited my question. My childs db are on different server and my parent db is on seperate server

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673087/how-to-maintain-foreign-key-constraint-across-different-databases