# MySQL InnoDB foreign key between different port databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to know if it's possible in InnoDB in MySQL to have a table(db:3306 with password) with foreign key that references another table in a different port database(db:3307 with no password)? And if so, how this can be done ?

I have tried this one

```
ALTER TABLE `treat_well`.`tw_venue` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_tw_venue_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
REFERENCES `bitnami_dreamfactory`.`user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

It throws error as follows

> Error Code : 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Advanced Thanks..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3905013/

Comment: @Drew that link refers to connect via same port i tried that one it's not working. Actually i'm trying to connect two dbs via different ports.

Comment: What you are describing lacks a ton of detail for anyone to help. But if you are saying FK's across two different servers out of the box? No. What is confusing is that it is not a db with a listening port. It is a server.

Comment: I have two databases in two ports(3306,3307) of server. I want to set the foreign key constraint between two tables' user_id  of their databases.

Comment: describe your server setup. How many physical servers. Let's give them names. How many daemon instances. We don't have time for vagueness. Trying to help

Comment: i have installed the wamp server its database server is running port 3307 after it i have installed the dreamfactory its mariadb is running port 3306.

Comment: Look at this question for 2 separate servers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673087

Comment: This is the link that i expect.  Thanks