# MySQL InnoDB foreign key remotely between different databases

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I am interested in referencing a table (InnoDB in MySQL) with foreign key that references another table in a different database **not**on the same machine. 
The two MySQL servers with the two databases are on the same network and can be reached remotely from one another.

Is this a set-up possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible, but I cannot find a specific reference in the documentation.  Two databases on the same server, though, is definitely possible.  Bill Karwin provides one solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673087/how-to-maintain-foreign-key-constraint-across-different-databases.

Comment: It is not possible to do this with *real* foreign keys, but it is possible to *emulate* it to a certain extent with a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) built out of `BEFORE` triggers and federated tables, similar to what I use in one particular place to cover someone else's design flaw: a group's attributes are authoritative on one db server but membership is authoritative on another... yet members must be compatible with group attributes. (!?) I prevent modification of attributes on groups with >0 members using this. Horrible but works. Interested?

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right is impossible :( thanks guys